# How does Android know which API an application targets?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm building an Android application using Xamarin. Visual Studio allows you to specify the target and minimum SDK level for Android, and this seems to work correctly, as decompiling the APK shows these attributes on the `manifest` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
platformBuildVersionCode="25" platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1"
```

Please not that this is not the manifest file in the *project*, but rather the manifest file *bundled in the final application*. The latter does not have `uses-sdk` values.

However, I don't seem to be getting the expected functionality at runtime for targeting this version. Specifically, the app never asks for runtime permissions (introduced in API 23 IIRC), and when you try to revoke a permission on the app, you get this message:

> This app was designed for an older version of Android. Denying permission may cause it to no longer function as intended.

This has been noted on several devices running above API 23, including a Pixel, which should be running stock Android and have no issues with detecting SDK version.

How is Android deciding which SDK version I'm targeting if it's not using the manifest values? How can I ensure my app will have access to API 23 features at runtime?

Comment: Those are not the attributes one would look at to determine the target and minimum SDK. What _do_ the `targetSdk` and `minSdk` attributes say? c.f. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: these are not the values in the pre-compilation AndroidManifest, but rather the AndroidManifest bundled in the APK. I compared the manifest to another app that works as expected and found similar attributes.

Comment: Right, but the `uses-sdk` element should still be present. In theory, it should match the two attributes you've quoted in your post -- however, since you are not seeing expected results we must consider the possibility there is some discrepancy.

Comment: I don't disagree! I'm pretty sure `uses-sdk` is used at build time only; I don't see it in the final APK. The `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the project (before compilation) does have the proper `uses-sdk` values.

Comment: Gotcha. That is indeed very strange. What does the generated manifest contain in terms of permission elements?

Comment: Internet, access network state, camera, read & write external storage, coarse location, fine location, location extra commands, Wi-Fi state, wake lock, and `com.google.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE`.

Comment: @TomG Actually, I inspected the manifest outside of Visual Studio's editor and found it was missing the `targetSdkVersion` value (even though the editor says it does have a target SDK version) and it now works! I'd still like to know how Android knows which version your'e targeting, however. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveRichey See [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html): `minSdkVersion` defaults to `1` if not present, and `targetSdkVersion` defaults to whatever `minSdkVersion` is (which would be `1` if neither are present).

Comment: Have you use` CheckSelfPermission` method when your app deployed on a  Android device which version is high then 23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this information is encoded in the signature of the APK, as the minimum SDK version is a parameter given to `apksigner`:

```
--min-sdk-version   Lowest API Level on which this APK's signatures will be
                    verified. By default, the value from AndroidManifest.xml
                    is used. The higher the value, the stronger security
                    parameters are used when signing.
```

I'm not 100% sure on this, but it seems like this is the only way Android could know without using the manifest directly, and it would explain why it was possible for the manifest value to not match the value seen at runtime.

Comment: The signer has three ways of signing an apk and it can omit legacy signature versions if min-sdk is high enough. I'm pretty sure the min-sdk is not written into the signature.